# Monotone Convergence Theorem - Lebesgue measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

One of the conditions for the monotone convergence theorem is that $f_n \uparrow f$ pointwise. Is there a version of this theorem for which $f_n \downarrow f$ pointwise? If there is, what are the other conditions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Look up dominated convergence.  Basically, when approaching from above, you need for the sequence of functions to eventually have finite integral, then you can do a subtraction to get out monotone convergence.  If the sequence always has infinite integral, it could converge to anything, imagine $f_n=1_{[n,\infty]}$, for example.

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit further?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you include the extra condition that $\int f_n < \infty$ for $n \geq N$, some $N \in \mathbb{N}$, you have a version of the Monotone Convergence Theorem:

**If $f_n$ measurable and $(f_n) \downarrow f$, then $\int f_n \downarrow \int f$.**

**Proof.** You can define $\int f := m(\mathcal{U}f)$, where $\mathcal{U}f = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R} \times [0, \infty): 0 \leq y < f(x)$ } (pictorially, this is the region between the graph of $f$ and the x-axis). We also denote the "undergraph" plus the graph of $f$ as: $\hat{\mathcal{U}}f := \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R} \times [0, \infty): 0 \leq y \leq f(x) \}$.

Note in particular that if $f_n \downarrow f$, then $\hat{\mathcal{U}}f_n \downarrow \hat{\mathcal{U}}f$, so by measure continuity, $m(\hat{\mathcal{U}}f_n) \downarrow m(\hat{\mathcal{U}}f)$. Also, if $f$ is measurable, then the graph itself, a zero set, will not contribute to $m(\hat{\mathcal{U}}f)$, so $m(\hat{\mathcal{U}}f) = m(\mathcal{U}f \sqcup \text{graph of $f$}) = m(\mathcal{U}f)$.

Using this information, we conclude that $\int f_n = m(\mathcal{U}f_n) = m(\hat{\mathcal{U}}f_n) \downarrow m(\hat{\mathcal{U}}f) = m(\mathcal{U}f) = \int f$.